# Android how to set AlarmManager alarm to go off at a random hour every day?

Tags: android

Up until now, every day at 11 o'clock an alarm manager triggers a procedure like so:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    long alarmTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    alarmTime = alarmTime + (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SyncReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1300, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Now I gotta change this procedure to go off at a random hour each day, how can I do that with the least amount of change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `setRepeating()` with `set()`. In `SyncReceiver`, choose the next random hour and `set()` a fresh alarm to trigger `SyncReceiver` at that time.

Comment: well what if the first random hour is 2 Am. Then the alarm goes off and in Sync Receiver a new Random says next hour is 4 AM - this will go 2 hours later, and not in the next day? Also what will happen if next random hour i 1 AM - the alarm will go off right away, and not in the next day. How do I guarantee that there will be only one alarm per calendar date?

Comment: @J.K.: You set the random hour on a `Date` object that is for tomorrow, not today.

Comment: what will happen if I replace setRepeating with setInexactRepeating, will that introduce enough randomness?

Comment: @J.K.: I have no idea what "enough randomness" means. It certainly will not guarantee that you will get only one event every calendar day.